# How to import flow in one module to a state in another module in Corda?

Tags: corda

While trying "Event-Scheduling" concept in Corda ,I'm facing this Issue.
I need to import a flow in state ,but ,my project structure has flows and states in two different modules.Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the first module as a dependency of the second. [Here](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-kotlin/blob/release-V3/cordapp/build.gradle#L58) is an example using Gradle from the Kotlin CorDapp Template:

```
cordapp project(":cordapp-contracts-states")
```

The instructions for having your CorDapp depend on a CorDapp in another module are [here](https://docs.corda.net/cordapp-build-systems.html#dependencies-on-other-cordapps).

Comment: yaa..I already done this.But I can't invoke the flow inside the nextScheduledActivity() function which is defined in state.I can't import the flow inside state even though I added the dependency

Comment: Ah! There is an alternative `FlowLogicRefFactory.create` which takes the class-name as a string, rather than an actual class. You can use this.